# AngularJS ng-repeat orderBy not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to order a list of objects using Angular's orderBy in a table.

```
<div ng-repeat="processing in model.Processings" class="onePaddingBottom">
    <table datatable="ng" class="table-bordered">

        <tbody >
            <tr ng-repeat="pointer in processing.ProcessingPointers | orderBy:'Sequence'" >
                <td class="col-md-1">

                    <input type="text" ng-model="pointer.Sequence" readonly=""/>
                </td>
                <td><input ng-model="pointer.Name" /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Controller

```
$scope.model = new Model()
```

Models

```
var Model = function () {
    this.Processings = [];  // array of Processings seen below
    this.categories = [];
    this.Rules = [];
};

var Processing = function (carrierService) {
    this.ProcessingId = 0;
    this.categoryId = 1;
    this.Rules = [];
    this.category = "";
    this.ProcessingPointers = [];  // array of Pointers seen below.
}

var Pointer = function () {
    this.ProcessingID = 0;
    this.ProcessingRuleTypeID = 0;
    this.Sequence = 0;
    this.Name = "";
    // other data items 
}
```

When my table is populated the order of the objects is not correct.  The top item in the sequence is always the highest item with the remainder of the items in order.  Thus if my array of Pointers was

```
var pointers = [
    {Sequence: 1, Name:"John"},
    {Sequence: 2, Name:"Jane"},
    {Sequence: 3, Name:"Joe"},
    {Sequence: 4, Name:"Jill"}
];
```

The order is alway 4, 1, 2, 3.  What is causing this ordering?

**Update**

Below is a screenshot.

[image]

Sequence seems to work on IE but not on Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error. Did a plnkr on this (http://plnkr.co/edit/8Cpxpshe6EE4dp8kpifu?p=preview), first thought it is a problem with the nested ng-repeat - but nervetheless in my plnkr it's working.

Comment: I updated the issue since it seems to be happening in Chrome and not IE.